# Distribution of $\bar{X}$ of n Bernoulli's

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to derive the distribution of $\bar{X}_n$ where $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ are iid $\sim \mathrm{Bern}(p)$. I used two approaches but I am debating myself and questioning which one would be correct (if any).

Method 1: Using MGF
I used the moment generating function and ended up with $\bar{X}_n \sim \mathrm{Bern}(p^n)$

Method 2:
I used the CLT and ended up with $\bar{X}_n \sim N(p, \sqrt{pq}/n$) for n being large.

I am not sure which one is correct (if any).

Can someone tell me if I am doing this right or not?

Thank you, 
I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

- For the first one, you are claiming that the average only take binary value.
- For the second one, what if $n$ is small.

Guide:

- Recall that sum of IID Bernoulli follows a binomial distribution $Bin(n, p)$.
- Average is simply dividing the sum by $n$.

Comment: Won't I get a Bernoulli again if I simply divided by n? Bin(n/n, p/n) => Bin(1, p/n) (one trial) => Bern(p/n)?

Comment: Suppose $n=2$, the values that you can get are $0, 0.5, 1$. It is possible to get value $0.5$, something that is not modelled by the Bernoulli distribution.